# Barman server unable to connect to Primary

Tags: postgresql, barman

I have created and followed instructions from the barman documentation. I have a primary Postgres and backup barman servers. I am able to ssh to primary server from back server without password. But when running any of the barman commands like `barman check Postgresdb-server` I am unable to get any response. At same time the wal archiving is working fine as I see the wal logs in backup server. Even `barman backup Postgresdb-server` is not responding. Is there anything that I am missing? The log file says it is impossible to take backup but other than that there is no other message. I am using the latest barman 2.1 and PostgreSQL 9.6.2

```
[Postgresdb-server]
description =  "Example of PostgreSQL Database (via Ssh)"
ssh_command = ssh postgres@pg
conninfo = host=pg user=barman dbname=postgres
backup_method = rsync
reuse_backup = link
archiver = on
```

Update: The issue was resolved after opening a firewall port 5432 for external connections. In this case opening port 5432 from backup/barman server to primary postgres server. This helped resolved the issue.

`psycopg2.connect("host=pg user=barman dbname=postgres")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "pg" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Comment: Is `conninfo` set correctly in your barman config? If you're using `backup_method=postgres`, do you have `streaming_conninfo` set? Did you add `pg_hba.conf` entries on the primary to accept these connections?

Comment: Updated my question with my conf file.. I am not using streaming replication but good old rsync/ssh

Comment: Again, is your primary's `pg_hba.conf` configured to accept connections from the barman server?

Comment: Yes `host all all barmanip/32 trust`

Comment: Can you connect to the primary from the barman server via `psql` using the same connection details? What do you mean by "unable to get any response", i.e. what exactly happens when you run `barman check`? You could try putting `log_level = DEBUG` in your `barman.conf` and see what it writes to the log.

Comment: I have changed the `log_level = DEBUG`. The only information i am missing from the above comment. Can you connect to the primary from the barman server via `psql` --> I don't have psql on my barman. Is that a requirement to install `psql` on backup server? All i have on my backup server is just barman. Do we have to install Postgres on barman server?

Comment: Barman doesn't need `psql`, it's just an easy way to test the connection. You could also do this via the Python library, which the barman package should have pulled in as a dependency. From the `python` interactive prompt, just type `import psycopg2` and then `psycopg2.connect("host=pg user=barman dbname=postgres")`.

Comment: I think the issue was that i did not have my firewall rule to open the port `5432` from outside connections. I think the `psycopg2.connect` help to identify that. Thanks for the tip. Will keep a note of this small python utility.